# How to construct complex list with if/else condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

I need to build a Python list-Dict object to be passed to an API (boto3) for inserting data into an AWS Aurora Serverless database. The data for the table columns are available in variables (gv_col1, gv_col2, etc.). The API input does not allow me to specify a variable if it is None and in such cases I need to pass  'isNull': True.

I'm building the list like this-

```
v_sql_parameters =  [
                           {'name': 'col1', 'value':{'stringValue': gv_col1}},
                           {'name': 'col2', 'value':{'longValue': gv_col2}},
                           {'name': 'col3', 'value':{'longValue': gv_col3}},
                           {'name': 'col4', 'value':{'stringValue': gv_col4}},
                           {'name': 'col5', 'value':{'doubleValue': gv_col5}}
                       ]
```

However if gv_col1 is None, it should become

```
v_sql_parameters =  [
                        {'name': 'col1', 'isNull': True},
                        {'name': 'col2', 'value':{'longValue': gv_col2}},
                        {'name': 'col3', 'value':{'longValue': gv_col3}},
                        {'name': 'col4', 'value':{'stringValue': gv_col4}},
                        {'name': 'col5', 'value':{'doubleValue': gv_col5}}
                    ]
```

How can I build such a list in Python? Any examples please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function to build your parameters that handles the logic inside there.

```
def make_param(name, valuetype, value):
    if (value == None):
        return {'name': name, 'isNull': True }
    else:
        return {'name': name, 'value':{valuetype: value}},

v_sql_parameters =  [
                        make_param('col1', 'stringValue', gv_col1),
                        make_param('col2', 'longValue', gv_col2),
                        make_param('col3', 'longValue', gv_col3),
                        make_param('col4', 'stringValue', gv_col4),
                        make_param('col5', 'doubleValue', gv_col5),
                    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Statement. This really solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions might help, but it might also make the code more unreadable later on compared to nested if else.

first create a list with all the variable values

```
gv_cols = [gv_col1,gv_col2,gv_col3,...]
```

and a list with all the types

```
gv_cols_types = ['longValue','stringValue',...]
```

then zip them together

```
gv_cols_list = zip(gv_cols_types,gv_cols)

v_sql_parameters = [{'name': 'col'+str(i+1), 'value':{col[0]: col[1]}} if col[1] != None else {'name': 'col'+str(i+1), 'isNull': True} for i,col in enumerate(gv_cols_list)]
```